# How to bring text to the left side?

Tags: html, css

Please refer: [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tkqew)

I want to bring this text towards left.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="icon-thread">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" class="optionsRadios2" value="option1"  checked="checked" title="Nenhum">
      <label class="radio" for="optionsRadios2"><i class="icon-ban-circle icon-stack-base text-error"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" class="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
      <label class="radio" for="optionsRadios2"><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-moon"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" class="optionsRadios2" value="option3">
      <label class="radio" for="optionsRadios2"><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-plane"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css);

body{
  background:#314559
}

.icon-thread input[type='radio'] {
  opacity: 0;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%
}

.icon-thread input[type='radio'] + label {
  margin:.6em;
  color: #B1B1B1;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff
}

.icon-thread input[type='radio']:checked + label{
  color:#5F6F81
}

.icon-thread li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin:2% 0 1%
}

.icon-thread ul{
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #D1D8DD;
  background:#FAFAFA;
  text-align:right
}
```

Comment: Remove text-align: right; from class .icon-thread ul this is the cause of input field aligning to right.

Comment: You should include relevant code within your question and make it clean what you are referring to within the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code: You can add other `Tags` comma separated

If you want just inside the class `.icon-thread`:

```
p,h1,h2,h3.icon-thread{
  text-align:left;
}
```

If you want all text appears left:

```
p,h1,h2,h3{
  text-align:left;
}
```

et voilà

Comment: I want just Hello to shift left. Not the icons.

Comment: Just add `.f{text-align:left;margin:-50px 0px 0px 40px;}`

Answer (score 0):

```
.icon-thread ul
{
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #D1D8DD;
    background:#FAFAFA;
    text-align:left;
}
```

for the ul tag just make the text align right to left

Comment: But I only want text to shift towards left. Not the icons.